# AJAX submit no data on POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I don't appear to have any data being sent when a form is submitted through jquery

A snippet of my issue (code reduced to simplify):

head:

```
        <script>

function dSubmit(formName, formAction, fieldsToCheck, divToHide){


        // No Errors process form


var url = formAction; // the script where you handle the form input.

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#" + formName).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {alert(data)}
     });

return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.


}
</script>
```

body:

```
<a onclick="dSubmit('treatmentDetails','treatments/processTreatments.php','','')"><img style="width:35px;" src="i/update-icon.png"/></a>


<form name="treatmentdetails" id="treatmentdetails" 

action="processTreatments.php" method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="treatmentName" value="<?php echo $treatment;?>"/>
<input type="text" name="treatmentId" value="<?php echo $treatmentId;?>"/><br>

    </form>
```

php (treatments/processTreatments.php):

```
    $table  =   $dbPrefix."treatmentsOptions";

$treatmentId = $_POST['treatmentId'];
$treatmentName  = $_POST['treatmentName'];
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET name='$treatmentName' WHERE id='$treatmentId'");

echo "variables = id: $treatmentId name: $treatmentName"; // according to jquery submit neither variable appear
```

Comment: php received an ajax request?  Also, is there an error in ajax processing?

Comment: Have you looked at the console for errors? Have you tried printing the form data to the console before submitting via AJAX?

Comment: If I add a standard submit button and avoid using ajax then the database is updated however upon ajax submission the alert reads 'variables = id: name:' with no data and no database update takes place.  I wasn't sure if the serialize section is working or if I need to cycle through the inputs (they will vary from form to form).  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typo `treatmentDetails`, fix to `treatmentdetails`.

`$("#treatmentDetails").serialize()` is return empty string.

your correct code is:

```
<a onclick="dSubmit('treatmentdetails','treatments/processTreatments.php','','')"><img style="width:35px;" src="i/update-icon.png"/></a>
```

Comment: What a newbie error and I've been doing this stuff for years! Sometimes you can't see the obvious, thank you very very much!